# Figuring out current torch state

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, mediastream

Suppose I have a MediaStream captured through getUserMedia.  If this is a rear facing camera on a smartphone, I can turn on/off the light like so:

```
const videoTrack = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
videoTrack.applyConstraints({
  advanced: [
    { torch: true }
  ]
});
```

I would like to toggle this state, so I need to figure out a way to get it.  It does seem to be available via `getSettings()`:

```
videoTrack.getSettings().torch; // false
```

However, it always seems to return `false` no matter what I set the current constraints to.

What is the correct method for getting the state of the `torch`, and ideally other advanced constraints of the video stream/camera?

Comment: What browser and device are you getting this to work on?

Comment: @jib Chrome on Android

Comment: [Not working for me](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/5e8nov9L/) in either Chrome 75 or Canary on a Samsung S8.

Comment: @jib Your fiddle works intermittently for me on Chrome v75.0.3770.143 on Android on a Google Pixel (original).  The first load worked.  Subsequent couple of reloads didn't.  Third did.  Hmmm, must be an issue of timing.  I wonder if that's the issue you're running into on your phone, or if maybe device support is narrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just anecdotally, support for [torch](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-image/#dom-mediatrackconstraintset-torch) seems limited to Chrome for Android on devices like the Google Pixel at the moment.

About your code, the [applyConstraints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/applyConstraints) method is *asynchronous*. It takes time for the setting to apply, so you must await the [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) it returns, before you can read the result of the modification. Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/5e8nov9L/) using `async`/`await`:

```
async function (mediaStream) {
  const videoTrack = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];

  await videoTrack.applyConstraints({torch: true});
  console.log(videoTrack.getSettings().torch); // true
};
```

...or using `then` to form a promise chain:

```
function (mediaStream) {
  const videoTrack = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];

  return videoTrack.applyConstraints({torch: true})
    .then(() => console.log(videoTrack.getSettings().torch)); // true
};
```

Thirdly, there's nothing advanced about `advanced: []`, an older more complicated syntax. Today's [modern syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Parameters) is simpler.